# How to add my own tool in sakai 2.9 like announcement?

Tags: sakai

I am new to sakai, i want to add my own tool in sakai source code like announcement,syllabus...etc That tool having some my own functionality for this what i have to do, how can i develop my own tool in sakai.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the archetypes to get you started, then customise it. When you are comfortable you can change the UI layer to be whatever you like.

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Developer+Tools

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solid "base" tool shell to begin with tool development my recommendation would be to start here: ["Sakai Wicket Maven Archetype"](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Sakai+Wicket+Maven+Archetype). There are a few other very good archetypes available but are often outdated and may cause you some problems based on my experience. This has been the one I've had the most success with.

This uses [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) but does not mean you have to use Wicket to develop further with it. Make sure to pull the 1.2 version as last check the binaries for the others were not available yet so replace `-DarchetypeVersion=1.4.1` with `-DarchetypeVersion=1.2` It will compile and deploy successfully as a tool "as-is" that you can modify as needed. It also allows you to code in Java to directly access the sakai API and pull from its database or even add your own tables. I've successfully used it with NetBeans 8.0.1 and MySQL 5.6 under Windows 7 with Maven 3.2.3 and Sakai 10.1.

The code is well-documented and is no-frills but with enough varied functional use examples to allow you to do "almost" anything you want. The wicket manual is 600+ pages but in my experience you should be able to accomplish a lot just by looking at the code in the archetype.